# App Store image not showing up in Xcode

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, resources

I am making an app with Cordova 6.5, Angular 1.5, and Ionic 1.3.5.

I see that there is a new App Store Icon for iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/
It's 1024.

I have added this image to my resources directory:
resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png

I have added this image to config.xml:

But every time I build my project and go into Xcode I need to manually drag and drop the image in. I am not sure what's wrong.

Edit:
I updated my cli to cordova 8.0.0. 
I also added both of these files to my config.xml file:

The problem is that the 2 images are not being copied into the Images.xcassets folder under platforms/ios

Answer (score 2):

The 1024 image is a new thing and you are using a very old Cordova CLI version. So you have to update cordova-ios platform to at least 4.5.1 to make it work. I would recommend 4.5.4 as it's the latest and fixes other bugs.

So remove the ios platform and add it like this

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.5.4
```

Beware that if you did any manual change in the Xcode project, it will be lost.

You also might need to update the Cordova CLI to 8.

Comment: I've got the cordova-ios version 4.5.4. Do you still think it could be the cli version?

Comment: Not sure, try at least with 7.1.0 as that was the version pinning cordova-ios 4.5.x. Also, run `corodova prepare ios`, I think sometimes the icons are not copied if you don't run that

Comment: I have tested with Cordova CLI 8, cordova-ios 4.5.4 and it's working fine. Do you have the icon entry in your config.xml? `<icon height="1024" src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />`. You can try to remove and re add the platform